# How does this form of Poincare's inequality for self-adjoint matrices hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm reading "Introduction to Matrix Analysis and Applications" by Hiai and Petz, and they state Theorem 1.26 ("Poincare's Inequality") as follows:

Let $A\in B(H)$ be a self-adjoint operator with eigenvalues $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq ...\geq \lambda_n$ and let $K$ be a k-dimensional subspace of $H$. Then there are unit vectors $x,y\in K$ such that $\langle x,Ax\rangle \leq \lambda_k$ and $\langle y,Ay\rangle \geq \lambda_k$.

They give a way to find $x$, but as far as I can tell there won't necessarily be a $y$. Consider the matrix:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 5&0&0&0&0\\0&4&0&0&0\\0&0&3&0&0\\0&0&0&2&0&\\0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Let k = 2, and $K=span\left(\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\right)$. Then for any unit vector $x\in K$, $\langle x,Ax\rangle \leq 2$, so how can there be a $y\in K$ such that $\langle y,Ay\rangle \geq \lambda_2 = 4$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result as you quoted it is wrong.  Perhaps the book has a misprint.

The correct statement is that in a $k$-dimensional subspace $K$ of the $n$-dimensional space $H$, there are unit vectors $x, y$ with $\langle x, Ax \rangle \le \lambda_k$ and $\langle y, Ay \rangle \ge \lambda_{n+1-k}$.

In this case with $n=5$, $k = 2$, $\langle x, Ax \rangle \le 4$ and $\langle y, A y \rangle \ge 2$.